# Saving a domain object in grails

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class, bootstrapping

I can't **save** the domain objects in grails on **Windows 8.1** and **Centos 7**. Whenever I try to create an empty domain class and save it in `BootStrap.groovy`, I'm always getting the same error message after running the application:

```
Error |
2014-11-10 14:53:44,225 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the appl
ication: Method on class [com.test.Book] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test
 using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
Message: Method on class [com.test.Book] was used outside of a Grails application. If running in the context of a test
 using the mocking API or bootstrap Grails correctly.
    Line | Method
->>    5 | doCall                           in BootStrap$_closure1
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    327 | evaluateEnvironmentSpecificBlock in grails.util.Environment
|    320 | executeForEnvironment . . . . .  in     ''
|    296 | executeForCurrentEnvironment     in     ''
|    262 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1145 | runWorker                        in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . . . . . . . . . . .  in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run                              in java.lang.Thread
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

My domain class:

```
package com.test

class Book {
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

BootStrap.groovy:

```
import com.test.Book
class BootStrap {

    def init = { servletContext ->
        new Book(name: "My Book").save()
    }
    def destroy = {
    }
}
```

I tried with both **2.4.3** and **2.4.4** versions of grails. My jdk version is **1.7.0_71** (Tried with jdk6 and jdk8, too). The interesting is, I tried the exact steps on Ubuntu and OpenSuse and I've managed to save the object without problem. So, what can be the problem?

Regards,

Comment: Is `Book.groovy` defined in `grails-app/domain/com/test/`?  Are you using the default Hibernate plugin (look in `BuildConfig.groovy`)?

Comment: I've created the domain class using the create-domain-class command so I have Book.groovy file in the grails-app/domain/com/test folder. And I'm using the default hibernate plugin which is: hibernate4:4.3.6.1.

Comment: Did this application go through an upgrade path from an older version of Grails?  If some of your code was compiled with an older version of Grails, potentially this could happen (depending on a number of other factors).  If unsure, verify that the problem still happens after running `grails clean`.

Comment: The problem is, I get that error message on a new project. Simply, I'm creating a new project and creating an empty domain class. When I try to save it in BootStrap, it fails.

Comment: I don't know what might be wrong.  If you file a JIRA at https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS with the details, we will take a look.  Sorry for the trouble.

Comment: I'll post it. Thank you for help.

Comment: could it be possible your GRAILS_HOME is set differently for these different machines??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved. It seems grails have problems with **language packages** of the Operating System. I was using **Turkish** language pack of Windows and Centos. Now I've changed it to **English** and the problem is solved.